# SimpleCart JS: How can I know if a product it's correctly sold?

Tags: javascript, simplecart

I'm trying http://simplecartjs.org – 
There is a way to know if a user purchas and paid an item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the documentation of this cart application you will see that there are several checkout options available.
see for e.g.: http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/paypal

So you can link your SimpleCart to one of those checkout providers and you will have to look for completed payments on those sites.

Of course you have the option to use your own checkout method by using [SendForm](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/sendform-checkout) but then you'll have to write that by yourself.

There are also several event callbacks for the checkout process like `checkoutSuccess`, `checkoutFail` and `beforeCheckout` that you can use.

```
simpleCart({
    checkout: {
        type: "PayPal" ,
        email: "you@yours.com"
    },
    checkoutSuccess    : null, /* insert your function call here */
    checkoutFail       : null,
    beforeCheckout     : null
});
```

instead of `null` you simply have to insert your function calls.

Comment: Ok, then I must look into PayPal to know if an item it's correctly sold and then update MANUALLY my DB of items?

Comment: This is a very simple cart application as the name says. It runs completely on the client side. If you wish, you can alter the javascript code execute some server side code (like php) to manipulate your DB items. But you'll need to know what you are doing. Shopping websites isn't something for the first hello world web application.

Comment: I'm not at the first hello world web application. :)
Did you have ever used this application? 
Do you know WHERE (and the best phase) where I can make some ajax call to server to manipulate my DB items?

I was thinking after PayPal checkout, but the question is:
PayPal send to me some ref code or parameter in the url to identify the correct item sold?

If you have any others ideas, I'm all ears :)

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope this helps. It's also very hard to give helpful answers to such short questions. It's always better you give as much information about the problem and where you're stuck as you can.